# How to get bounding box based on distance from given point?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I need restrict map area to 5km radius around given point. 
How can I get appropriate bounding box using mapbox-gl-js or turf?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer to get a feature in size of the radius that you want and then use http://turfjs.org/docs/#bbox to get the bbox.

```js
var point = turf.point([-90.548630, 14.616599]);
var buffered = turf.buffer(point, 5, {units:'kilometers'});
var bbox = turf.bbox(buffered);
console.log(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can use turf.point for initial.
`var point = turf.point([-90.548630, 14.616599])`

Answer (score 4):

**Buffer API has changed.** Buffer's optional argument needs to be an object like so:

```
var point = turf.point([-90.548630, 14.616599]);
var buffered = turf.buffer(point, 5, {units:'kilometers'}); /// notice 'units'
var bbox = turf.bbox(buffered);
console.log(turf.bboxPolygon(bbox));
```

Comment: Please comment the post if the API has changed and don't duplicate my answer with a redundant one

Comment: Your approach was outdated and misleading. I'm happy you copied over the fix.